# I want a function to be fired whenever one option of a radio element is checked. The radio elements are dynamically created by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, callback

I want to place a function on input radio elements. These input radio elements are created dynamically by using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). One dynamically-created (by the user's click) input element looks as follows:

```
<div class="below">
    <input type="radio" value="information" name="option0"/>
    Information
    <input type="radio" value="communication" name="option0"/>
    Communication
    <input type="radio" value="goods" name="option0"/>
    Goods
    <input type="radio" value="attention" name="option0"/>
    Attention
</div>
```

I wrote the function as follows:

```
$('input:radio').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) { // or $(this).attr('checked')
        alert(this.value); // or alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

I found that this doesn't work because `$('input:radio')` can only work on static input radio elements, not dynamically-created input radio elements by using jQuery.

Of course, I can embed the callback code in input radio elements, so it looks as follows.

```
<div class="below">
    <input type="radio" value="information" name="option0" onclick="myfunction()" />
    Information
    <input type="radio" value="communication" name="option0"  onclick="myfunction()" />
    Communication
    <input type="radio" value="goods" name="option0" onclick="myfunction()" />
    Goods
    <input type="radio" value="attention" name="option0" onclick="myfunction()" />
    Attention
</div>
```

Is there another elegant way to do it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `radio` elements are created programmatically your selector cannot find them, because they don't exist yet.

You could either, bind the `click` event when you create the elements as [@Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794157/i-want-a-function-to-be-fired-whenever-one-option-of-a-radio-element-is-checked/1794275#1794275) suggests, or could use [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live):

```
$('input:radio').live('click', function () {
  if (this.checked) { // or $(this).attr('checked')
    alert(this.value); // or alert($(this).val());
  }
});
```

The `live` function binds an event handler for all current *and future* matched elements, using [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/).

It currently supports the following events: `click`, `dblclick`, `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mousemove`, `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `keydown`, `keypress`, `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).
Live will bind a handler to an event (like click) or to a custom event for all current - and future - matched element.

```
$('input:radio').live('click', function(){
    alert(this.value);
    }
);
```

Comment: Do I still have to embed onclick="myfunction()" in radio elements? It doesn't work when I don't write it. How can a function be fired without onclick="myfunction()"?

Comment: @Steven No, you don't and shouldn't embed `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the click event as you create each input node.

```
// Create the node however you are already doing it
var node = document.createElement("input");
node.setAttribute("type", "radio");
node.setAttribute("name", "option0");
// etc

// And then attach the click event
$(node).click(function () {
    if (this.checked) { // or $(this).attr('checked')
      alert(this.value); // or alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: There are more than one radio input element, so node.setAttribute("name", "option0"); is not suitable. There are option1, option2,...

Comment: Radio buttons have to have the same to be grouped and function like radio buttons.  That is also what you have in your example code.